# Why my Java Card applet returns 16 bytes of zero instead of AES encrypted value?

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard

The below program is written to encrypt 16 bytes of incoming APDU command data section and return that encrypted value:

```
public class DoAES extends Applet {

    //Required Objects
    static Cipher myCipher;
    static AESKey myAESKey;
    byte[] cipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0x10, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
    //Supported APDU commands INS byte
    final static byte SET_KEY = (byte) 0x12;
    final static byte WRITE_TEXT = (byte) 0x04;
    final static byte READ_TEXT = (byte) 0xC0;

    private DoAES() {

        try {
            myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_ECB_NOPAD, false);
            myAESKey = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,
                    KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        (new DoAES()).register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        if ((buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0x00FF) != 0x80) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        try {
            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case SET_KEY:
                    myAESKey.setKey(buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
                    myCipher.init(myAESKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
                    break;

                case WRITE_TEXT:
                    myCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) 0x10, cipheredData, (short) 0);
                    break;

                case READ_TEXT:
                    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(cipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) 0x10);
                    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) 0x10);
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it only returns zero:

```
OSC:> opensc-tool.exe -s 00a4040006010203040501 -s 801200001000112233445566778899aabbccddeeff -s 80c00000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 01
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 80 12 00 00 10 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 80 C0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
```

To solve this issue, I replace

```
    byte[] cipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0x10, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
```

with:

```
    byte[] cipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0x10, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
```

and also with

```
    byte[] cipheredData = new byte[16];
```

But nothing changed!

Note that as I want to do a side channel attack on the card, I want to have a minimal use of EEPROM and want to use RAM instead. So if you have any comment to improve the program in a way that I can use EEPROM less, please let me know.

And also note that I "must" use three different commands for `set_key`, `write_text` and `read_text` because of my side channel board. I mean don't suggest ways to mix the commands.

Comment: The first replacing code is the same??

Comment: @GingerHead It was a miss typed. Corrected, thanks. :)

Comment: What exactly is the point of passing three unused parameters to the `install()` method?

Comment: @EJP Those are mandatory parameters for `install()` method in javacard specifications. I don't directly use them, but the Java Card Runtime Environment use them to create instance of the incoming applet. For example the AID (Applet Identifier) of the installing applet is specified in these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped encryption APDU please send

```
80 04 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

Where 11..11 is data to encrypt.

Then try reading array by `80 C0 00 00`

Comment: Anurag, Is there any way to define `myAESKey` in RAM instead of a static field(and in EEPROM)?

Comment: @Abraham It can not go to RAM but you can use "(AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_RESET, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);" it will implicitly clear the key after reset.

Answer (score 1):

First of all these two are the same:

> To solve this issue, I replace
>
> ```
>     byte[] cipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0x10, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
>     byte[] cipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0x10, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
> ```

second:

now *`cipheredData`* doesn't contain anything, it's an empty byte array, so doesn't do any good neither in case of `write_text` nor in case of `read_text`.

Don't you need to encrypt the **APDU**???

Are you missing something?

### Update

Since you were asking about saving keys:

*For generating key:*

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256); 
SecretKey myKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

*For saving key:*

```
char[] hex = encodeHex(key.getEncoded());
writeKeyToFile(file, String.valueOf(hex));
```

*For loading saved key:*

```
String keyHex = new String(readFileToByteArray(file));
byte[] encoded = decodeHex(keyHex.toCharArray());
SecretKey myKey = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
```

Comment: Ah! you are right! I missed `WRITE_TEXT` APDU command(Encrypt command)!! Both answers are correct, but as dear Anurag answered first, I checked his answer. Thank you :)

Comment: It's OK, it's fine, no worries, you can always change your decision later.

Comment: @Abraham OK, now it's updated according to your needs

Comment: Thank you again dear friend. I think you mixed Java APIs and JavaCard APIs. There is no `KeyGenerator`, `readFileToBytes` and `decodeHex` classes in Java Card APIs. Moreover I don't want to generate keys on the card, I want to set the key from outside. Everyrhing worksnfine now. I just want to malenit.more efficient to use RAM instead of EEPROM. thanks :)